# Turn array of words into string with php

Tags: php

I have an array of keywords...

(array) -> (house, table, horse, tree)

I need to create a string from that like this:

house+table+horse+tree

How can I do this with PHP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`implode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

```
$string = implode('+', array(house, table, horse, tree));
```